# Can the scabbard hold a castle sword

Tags: piece-information

I wonder if the Dark Gray Minifigure, Weapon Sword, Shortsword part No: 3847a fits in the Minifigure, Utensil Scabbard with Shoulder Strap part No: 95348

[Scabbard on bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=95348&idColor=120#T=S&C=120&O=%7B%22color%22:120,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image: Scabbard]

[Sword on bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3847&name=Minifig,%20Weapon%20Sword,%20Shortsword&category=%5BMinifig,%20Weapon%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image: Sword]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does, and it fits beautifully! In fact, it's one of my favorite combinations as the sword is not too long and thus doesn't drag on the ground.

Comment: I just took a picture for you and was trying to include it, but for some reason I couldn't post. I kept getting the error message "body is missing". I'm not sure what that means. Sorry about that.